# How to remove this space AFTER inline-block?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure where this space is coming from (marked in red in attached image)? Any pointers?

[image: Image of strange space]
This is a 'Coming soon' page with mainly a masthead and a mastfoot, and some social links positioned differently if on mobile or desktop. I'm having problems with the mobile view.

> This is the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="masthead">
  <div class="masthead-bg"></div>
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-12 my-auto">
        <div class="masthead-content text-white py-5 py-md-0">
          <h1 class="mb-3">Register</h1>
          <p class="mb-5">Building a X.
          We're building X for you. <strong>Request an invitation for early access using the form below!</strong></p>
          <form action="https://hen.us18.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" target="_blank">
            <input type="hidden" name="u" value="377b993ba697354f6584371c9">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="e1c7ba1f4b">
            <div class="input-group input-group-newsletter">
              <input type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" size="25" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email..." aria-label="Enter email..." aria-describedby="basic-addon">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Notify Me!</button>
              </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="ht" value="f5b0455009025ab4743b2ecc932316028905c673:MTUzMTgyNjMzMC43NDM3">
                <input type="hidden" name="mc_signupsource" value="hosted">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="mastfoot">
      <div class="inner-mastfoot">
        &copy; 2018 X Ltd. All Rights Reserved. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; • 
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="/legal">Legal</a> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    • &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
  </div>

<div class="social-icons">
  <ul class="list-unstyled text-center mb-0">
    <li class="list-unstyled-item">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-unstyled-item">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-unstyled-item">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-medium"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-unstyled-item">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-unstyled-item">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-unstyled-item">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> and the relevant CSS:

```css
.masthead .masthead-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 35rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 46, 102, .8);
  transform: skewY(4deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right
}

.social-icons {
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2
}

.social-icons ul {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center
}

.social-icons ul>li {
  margin-left: .75rem;
  margin-right: .75rem;
  display: inline-block
}

.social-icons ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 46, 102, .8);
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem
}

.mastfoot {
  color: #262626;
  color: rgba(26, 26, 26, .5);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 2
}

.inner-mastfoot {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I can tell - in this case, on desktop by resizing my window to be as thin as a mobile screen - it's because your content isn't tall enough to fill the screen.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cmyr.png

Your mystery space is just the height of the `<body>`, unfilled by content.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look!

I guess the blue (given this is responsive) should have come further down reducing the gap. 

Looking into my browser console (mobile view) the blue extends further, but there is still an enormous empty space. https://i.imgur.com/N0D5Miu.png

So, how can I extend the blue further?

Comment: For a rough, simple solution, try setting the height on .masthead to 80%.